# how to stop "docker run -it certbot/certbot"?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, images, centos, certbot

I'm newbie in docker. I use below command to run the certbot image twice:

```
docker run --rm certbot/certbot
```

I'd like to stop it but I can't. This command has started to produce many containers and these containers are automatically closed and produced again.

I have done the following:

1.Remove and kill containers

```
docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)
docker kill $(docker ps -q)
```

2.Through the following command, I tried to get the ID process and kill it:

```
ps aux | grep <containerId> | awk '{print $1 $2}'
```

then

```
kill -9 <processId>
```

But the ID process keeps changing.

3.I restarted Docker, even rebooted the whole server but still the problem persists.

I posted a screen record gif that shows that containers are constantly generated with different IDs and are automatically deleted.

[image: ScreenRecord]

How to resolve this problem?

Docker version 24.0.2, build cb74dfc
CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a swarm service, it will keep recreating the container everytime it fails, which is expected and The certbot service is constantly failing.

I disabled swarm mode with below command and re-initialized swarm again and my problem has been solved.

```
docker swarm leave --force
docker swarm init
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check the logs and see if something is notable there first.

```
 # docker logs 459979a55425
    [2024-01-30 23:56:18 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
    [2024-01-30 23:56:18 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (1)
    [2024-01-30 23:56:18 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
    ...
```

And try monitoring `events` while the container is active. This would need to be run in another terminal:

```
# docker events
2024-02-29T06:59:09.512867172-06:00 network connect ...(container=...b7fda34f83a, name=bridge, type=bridge)
...
```

The check if there is a restart policy for some reason (https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/).

```
# docker inspect 413071a51305
           ...
           "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            ...
```

If restart is set to `always` or similar, you can change it with something like below. There is more in the link above:

```
docker update --restart=no 459979a55425
```